# How to send and email via HTTP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, smtp

I've been sending emails using ASP.NET Smtp method and it's been working fine so far.

But now the structure of the business I'm working on has changed and they're requesting for new changes. First of all, now my email structure should be send to an API Email Service instead of an specific email address.

I've been searching for a while and I think I need to use HTTPRequest to do it, but I'm not exactly gifted when using C#. Here's my actual code (SMTP):

```
protected void Send_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Mailing Initialization
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mmsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

    mmsg.To.Add("receiver@gmail.com");
    mmsg.Body = TextBox1.Text;

    mmsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mmsg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");

    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient cliente = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

    cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "password");

    cliente.Port = 587;
    cliente.EnableSsl = true;

    cliente.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

    try
    {
        cliente.Send(mmsg);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        string message = "There is an error";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>if(window.confirm('" + (message) + "'))</script>");
    }
}
```

This needs to change, of course. I've been provided with an URL which is my API direction: https://apitp.trial/api/Online/Mail

The protocol must be HTTPS and the method must be POST.

I tell you, I've been searching for ages with no luck. Any ideas on how the structure of my mail should change to achieve this objective?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or links on how the API works? (i.e. the format of the data it uses)

Comment: Yes, according to the docs, the data should have this structure:

`code`{
  "Email": "neoristelecom@gmail.com",
  "CustomerNumber": 123456789,
  "ExternalMessageID": "1-222",
  "CustomerName": " Juan Perez",
  "CampaingName": " TestStress - EMAIL",
  "Extrafields": "opcional1;opcional2"
}

Comment: Okay so it looks like you need to send your data over in a JSON format. Do you know if there is any authentication on the API? (i.e. Tokens?)

Comment: Yes, actually. It's quite the process. They provide me with an user and a password. To that I must add the actual date, then change everything to Base64 and send it through the header: "api........?authorization:dTExMjIzMzpVRE1yYXZCVTkyMTlka0lkYlZJbHNWME0wd..." --- for example.

Comment: So it appears as though your company is using Basic Authentication on its Web API and securing it with Base64 encryption. I am writing something up to help you now, one moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks as thought your solution is shifting from using SMTP protocol to post messages to your mail server to using an API that ingests JSON.

From your comments I can see that it accepts a JSON format like this:

```json
{
  "Email": "example@example.com",
  "CustomerNumber": 123456789,
  "ExternalMessageID": "1-222",
  "CustomerName": "John Smith",
  "CampaingName": "A Campaign name",
  "Extrafields": "opcional1;opcional2"
}
```

I'm assuming The "Extrafields" node is a string and not an array as it appears to have that kind of format.

To work with Json in C# you'll need to import [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) into your solution if you haven't already. We can then use your existing event handler on your code above and use it to create the following object:

```cs
public class MailMessage
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string ExternalMessageID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CampaingName { get; set; }
    public string Extrafields { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use JSON.NET to serialize this object into a JSON string and POST that to your API in the format it is requiring. But being as your company also requires authentication, you will need to add a header to your POST request. I would also recommend using [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) for this to make your life easier.

You can use something like the following to get all of this up and running:

```cs
protected void Send_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creates new MailMessage Object
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage{
        Email = "someone@example.com",
        CustomerNumber = 123456789,
        ExternalMessageID = "1-222",
        CustomerName = "John Smith",
        CampaingName = "A Campaign name",
        Extrafields = "opcional1;opcional2"
    };

    var client = new RestClient("https://apitp.trial/"); //Makes a RestClient that will send your JSON to the server
    var request = new RestRequest("Online/Mail", Method.POST); //Sets up a Post Request your your desired API address
    request.AddHeader("api........?authorization", "INSERT YOUR BASE64 STRING HERE")
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); //Declares this request is JSOn formatted
    request.AddJsonBody(mm); //Serializes your MailMessage into a JSON string body in the request.
    var response = client.Execute(request); //Executes the Post Request and fills a response variable
}
```

Just insert your Base64 encrypted credentials where I have indicated and you can include some logic on the response variable to check it has processed properly. The Response variable has `StatusCode` on it, a code 200 will indicate a success.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to answer. This was a Top Notch solution! Thank you very much!